# Google Cloud Storage - Python check files by date (unzip gz files)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to randomly check how much the unzipped files from google cloud storage weigh. I want to check them by date.  So I have project = project_test
folder = folder_test
and in the folder are gz files with creation date.
I would like to pull random files from a particular date and unpack them.
I know how to access the bucket using python (list_blobs), but I don't know how to access the folder and select the files by date?

Answer (score 1):

With Cloud storage, the folder doesn't exist, it's only a prefix of the fully file path name.

In addition, [Cloud Storage doesn't offer the possibility to order by date](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) the objects. You need to perform this filter on your side, based on the object metadata.